# Bluetooth frequency-hopping advantage

Tags: bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy

i'm learning now the about Bluetooth (and BLE) and feel I need some explanation what the advantages of using frequency-hopping method. Can anyone please explain me in simple words (with examples, please) what we earn from the frequency-hopping?

Thanks!

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is not about programming.  It may be on topic at http://electronics.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 0):

Bluetooth has been designed to operate in noisy radio frequency environments, and uses a fast acknowledgement and frequency-hopping scheme to make the link **robust**, communication-wise. Bluetooth radio modules **avoid interference from other signals** by hopping to a new frequency after transmitting or receiving a packet.

Short packages and fast hopping **limit the impact of microwave ovens and other sources of disturbances**. Use of Forward Error Correction (FEC) **limits the impact of random noise on long-distance links.**

Example:

Considering the example at right, one realizes that hopping out-and-into a continous range of frequencies that are subject to noise, gives the communications link a **better chance to remedy transmission errors** when out of the disturbed frequencies, than would have been the case if the transmission had stayed for several timeslots within the noisy frequency range.

This argument does not hold true if the noise is spread over the whole frequency range in a random fashion, but sources of electro-magnetic noise usually give the pattern illustrated at right.

Comment: yes, i have also read this post. What i didn't understand was why it gives a better chance to remedy transmission errors

Comment: If you are in a constant frequency range (not hopping) and if that range contains noise, you will get transmission errors. BUT in case of bluetooth which does not stays in a constant freq range, it can change its freq which contains noise (by hopping)  and thus the noise is avoided, and thus it can remedy the transmission error.